# Not getting proper time duration in C

Tags: c

Let's consider a multi-sports race event like a triathlon. In this event when a person completes one activity (running, swimming, cycling etc) they immediately start a new activity after it. Suppose I have a device that continuously monitors the activity of the person. If you see the code, in "main()" function the volatile variable "activity" gets input from the device.
  The race was started 2 Hr before.

**My aim is to find out from how long till the current moment the person is in that particular activity. Say from past 1000 seconds the person is in running activity and earlier he/she was doing "cycling" (this could be anything in the general case). Also, the point is that the end time of previous activity is the start time current activity.**

The "triathlonTim()" function is called after every 1 sec continuously. When I calculate time as per my code, it's coming out to be 1 sec but actually it should be 1000 seconds. Here, time(NULL) and "stateTim" are updating continuously. "StateTim" variable must only be updated at the point when the person stops one activity and start other activity. So how do I fix it out? Any other idea or hint can also be useful to me.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

#define CYCLING 1
#define RUNNING 2
#define SWIMMING 3 

static int state ;
static int prevState ;
int stateTim;

void triathlonTim(int activity)
{
    int activtyTimDur ;

    if(activity == 10)  
    {
        printf("doing Cycling\n\r");
        state = CYCLING;
    }
    else if(activity == 20) 
    {
        printf("doing Running\n\r");
        state = RUNNING;
    }
    else if(activity == 30)
    {
        printf("doing Swimming\n\r");
        state = SWIMMING;
    }

    if(prevState != state)
    {
        activtyTimDur = time(NULL) - stateTim;
        stateTim =time(NULL);
        printf("Activity Time Duration = %d\n\r", activtyTimDur);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    volatile int activity;
    while(1)
    {
        triathlonTim(activity);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're doing `sleep(1)`, so why would it wait 1000 seconds?

Comment: Activity in main is not initialized and is passed by value to the function.  The fact that it is marked volatile is irrelevant.  You should assume volatile is irrelevant to you until you know enough to know when it is needed.  If it is any help, I’ve been programming in C for more than 30 years and have yet to use volatile in my own code.  You need to rethink.

Comment: **in "main()" function the volatile variable "activity" gets input from the device**  I don't see that in the code.

Comment: @Barmar the main function is called by the other function with current activity the person is doing . meaning the activity variable is getting value from externally (outside the main function)

Comment: @ThomasJager He's not expecting it to sleep 1000 seconds, he's just expecting the time between state changes to be 1000 seconds.

Comment: @Barmar yes you are right. I am just expecting the time between state changes to be 1000 seconds

Comment: You have two `if (activity == 2)`, one is CYCLING, the other is RUNNING.

Comment: @Barmar if condition value edited

Comment: Are you seeing 1000 "Doing Cycling" messages?

Comment: @user3559780 Can you explain in as much detail as possible how the modification of `activity` is happening and what role `volatile` plays? Because understanding that is essential to understanding your code and replicating your issue.

Comment: @Barmar yes . I see 1000 "Doing Cycling" messages.

Comment: And then you see "Doing Running", but it says the duration was only 1?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't think that's really relevant. It sounds like that part is working as expected, since he sees the expected messages printed. The problem is just with the duration calculation.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz lets take one example supoose race is started . the person 1st does CYCLING for 400 sec then RUNNING for 500 sec and then SWIMMING for 100 sec . Then the output sent from the device to the "activity " variable getting  in  "main" function will be 1. 10 for 400 seconds (2).20 for 500 sec and (3.) 30 for about 100 seconds

Comment: @user3559780 What does that mean though? Is `activity` memory mapped into hardware? Does some invasive debugger like process modify the memory `activity` is stored in? How would I replicate this error if I wanted to? If you haven't given us enough to replicate the error, it's always possible the error is coming from something you haven't given us. (Can you make a program that replicates this error for us without this complication? That would be best. If you can't, that demonstrates you haven't given us enough.) Also, where is `prevState` set/modified?

Comment: @Barmar if you see comparison condition between previous and current state (duration calculation) , for  "1000" seconds duration the condition  will be true .so each time stateTim varible is also getting updated .so difference is "1".

Comment: The problem is that you never set `prevState` to `state` when the state changes.

Comment: @Barmar yes u have the point . But where to set "prevState" . if i set it inside the 3 if-else (where activity values is compared) ,**after 1 second the prevState will become equal to current state** as the triathlon function is called after 1 second

Comment: 2 defects: `int stateTim;` --> `time_t stateTim;`, same for `int activtyTimDur`.  Suggest `stateTim =time(NULL);` in beginning of `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `prevState` whenever the state changes. Otherwise, every call will be treated as a state change.

```
    if(prevState != state)
    {
        activtyTimDur = time(NULL) - stateTim;
        stateTim =time(NULL);
        prevState = state;
        printf("Activity Time Duration = %d\n\r", activtyTimDur);
    }
```

Comment: but this case will fail when I am having activity order like CYCLING -> RUNNING-> CYCLING-> RUNNING-> SWIMMING

Comment: Why does the order matter? It just remembers any time you change activities.

Comment: @Barmer ok yes , u are right . But i think there could be issue that I could not find out the current ongoing activity duration unless it gets completed . Because when I am in current event prevState =state ,the duration cant get printed

Comment: You only print the duration when the state changes.

Comment: If they cycle for 1 minute, then run for 5 minutes, then cycle again, it should print Duration = 60 then Duration = 300

Comment: ok. with this I will get duration for previous activity, But can it be extended for current ongoing activity? also for the very 1st activity. ?.Because here ,I could not be able to print the 1000sec duration for RUNNING (any ongoing) activity.

Comment: Print that before the `if`.

Comment: But then you'll get Duration = 1, Duration = 2, Duration = 3, ... every time you call the function.

Comment: no, I think printing before "if" will continuously print previous state time duration only until ongoing activity ends.

Comment: So what are you expecting? You can't know that the activity has ended until the next activity starts.

Comment: I am expecting to find previous activity end time which will be start time of current activity . With this I could manage to find out the ongoing activity time duration.

Comment: That's what my answer does. Why do you think it doesn't work?